# Best way to handle a email lists in .Net

Tags: .net, email, list

In our project there will be a 5-6 groups of mail list that we will need to send notifications(100k-200k emails).

What is the best way to do this in .Net? 
Use custom classes, and custom smtp server? Or use some third party service(I don't find anything like that).

PS:We have 2 dedicated servers with win 2003 on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need some sort of email spooling application running. This means either write one yourself, or buy something (I don't know of any open source solutions for .net). [Smarter Mail](http://www.smartertools.com/SmarterMail/Features/Windows-Mail-Server-Software-Webmail-Exchange-Alternative.aspx) might do the trick. The free version supports the email spooling functions.

Answer (score 0):

What about the [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) namespace ?

It's part of the .net framework, and supports all the features I can think of.

Using something else at that stage of your project smells like premature optimization ; you'll still be able to switch to something else later on if you feel you're experiencing performance problems.

Comment: Yep I know. I wan't to be flexible enough in future.